# Can't write to a file using bottle with google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web, bottle

I have successfully deployed my python with bottle framework application in google app engine, however, I'm getting one of the most peculiar errors.

Whenever I try opening a file for writing I get the error,

```
Error: 500 Internal Server Error

Sorry, the requested URL 'http://issamcodemate.appspot.com/' caused an error:

Internal Server Error
```

This occurs when I execute any of the following statements in the server side,

```
f = open("Files/currentFile.txt",'r+') 
f = open("Files/currentFile.txt",'w') 
f = open("Files/currentFile.txt",'a')
```

Strangely, it works fine when I execute this code,

```
f = open("Files/currentFile.txt",'r')
```

But this is only for reading...

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Do you've permission to open that file in write mode?

Comment: I guess its the permission, but how would this be resolved? since its hosted

Comment: I've not used GAE, but try : [os.chmod](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.chmod)

Comment: Executing os.chmod alone causes the same error, perhaps it also requires permission to change the permission :). It must be somewhere in the settings to provide full admin access for the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot write to the local filesystem in GAE. Use the blobstore or Google Cloud Storage.